# if как сделать два условия

Tags: python, условия

я хотел чтобы в моем коде если вводить в терминал одно значение (input), либо тоже самое значение но с большой, выводилась некая пасхалка, но если я использую команду `or`, то неважно что я написал будет выводиться эта пасхалка, а если использую `and`, то пасхалка выводиться только в одном значении, первом.

```
print("Ваше имя")
name = input()
if name == "Бог" and "бог":
print("g")
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть два метода решения Вашей проблемы:

1. `or` (логическое "или")

Код будет выглядеть так:

```
name = input("Ваше имя: ")
if name == "Бог" or name == "бог":
    print("g")
```

2. Методы `lower()` либо `upper()`

Метод `lower()` возвращает копию строки, где все буквы будут с маленьким регистром, а метод `upper()` наоборот, с большим.

Код будет выглядеть так:

```
name = input("Ваше имя: ")
if name.lower() == 'бог':
    print("g")
```

Либо же так:

```
name = input("Ваше имя: ")
if name.upper() == 'БОГ':
    print("g")
```

Comment: спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо переписать условие, сравнение ввода должно производится оба раза:

```
name = input("Ваше имя: ")
if name == "Бог" or name == "бог":
    print("g")
```